# Issue with Url routing - Asp.Net MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I use "/Controller/ActionName" url format for my ajax calls. This pattern works fine with my development server that has this pattern

**/Controller/ActionName**

My application has been deployed to IIS with the following url pattern

**/domain/Controller/ActionName**

So whenever I call a resource it routes to /Controller/ActionName  instead of /domain/Controller/ActionName there by resulting in 404 error. Is there any quick fix for this by modifying the routeconfiguration such that it works on both the devl as well as the IIS.

Comment: If you use the `Url` helper as in `Url.Action("Action", "Controller")` it should take care of generating the right paths for you.

Comment: @Candide if I use the above , my url is rendered as /@Url.Action(%22action%22,%22controller%22)

Comment: because it is not inside my view . I need to use the relative path since all my js files are external

Comment: Using relative paths is a bad solution. Once you refactor code, it becomes difficult to ensure all paths point correctly. Use a global javascript variable to store what `~` points to, and rewrite the path in javascript code. Something like `"~/Controller/Action".replace("~", globalPath)`

Comment: Is there a way to make my root path like localhost/DomainName

Comment: Of course, that was implied in `globalPath`. You can set it in a global layout to whatever you want, since you have access to the HTTP Context in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you defining the relative urls "manually" as a string try not using a '/' in the beginning.

```
"Controller/ActionName"
```

#### Edit

What I've done the the past is included a Partial Razor View that is responsible of setting urls using @Url.Action()

Partial - Shared/JavascriptUrlsPartial.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function ($, app) {

    app.urls =
    {
      actionA: '@Url.Action("Controller", "ActionA")',
    };

  })(jQuery, app = app || {});

</script>
```

Then you reference the rendered url in javascript.

```
$.ajax({
  url: app.urls.actionA,
  //etc
})
```

This partial is then included in the _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: unfortunately it works only for  localhost/controller urls .. Not for  localhost/controller/action urls. It is rendered as localhost/controllerA/ControllerB/actionA

Comment: Edited with a alternative approach

Answer (score 0):

In my Razor view, we have Ajax calls like:

```
        var model = { searchId: searchId, newSearchName: searchName, newSearchDescription: description };
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Rename", "Search")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: JSON.stringify(model)
        })
```

We have not done anything special in local or production environment. We host the application on IIS 7.5.

I could not make out what's different in your case from your question and comments. If this does not solve the problem please add more information around your setup.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. As I have mentioned all my js are external hence I cannot use @Url.Action